# Why I cant update a message on CANoe via a Panel?

Tags: canoe

Im trying to update in "real time" the value of a message using a panel. However once the simulation starts , the panels shows this icon with a tooltip that indicates that "my signal value was not sent yet". Any idea why this happens ? The combo box is attached directly to a signal in the database and the related node is on the network simulation.

Note: I'm running this on CANoe v11

[image]

Comment: Each signal is part of a message, when the message has not yet been sent, the tooltip you have shown is displayed. How does your interaction layer configuration look like?

Answer (score 2):

The likely reason for this is, 'you are not using any interaction layer (IL)'.
When you change the value of a signal in the Panel, the signal has to be sent by something in the Simulation Setup. This "something" is the interaction layer.
Once you add the IL, changing the signal values in the Panel will change the value of that signal in the "signal server" of IL. So, whenever the message is sent by the IL after the change in the panel, the updated value will be sent.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I ended up fixing the problem. It seems that I had properly configured an IL however on database, the message that the panel was trying to change wasnt cofigured as periodic.

Comment: @RicardoMostalac - Consider to mark this Question as answered if you have received the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Last answer is correct, OR the signal has in dbc attribute

```
GenSigSwitchedByIgnition = 'Yes'
```

and the ‘SW-KL15’ is off.
(The ‘SW-KL15’ setting of the signal attribute `GenSigFuncType` allows assigning a
special behaviour to a signal depending on the value of `EnvKlemme15`.)